# Fastai - CUDA error: device-side assert triggered

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, fast-ai

I am using Fastai for Image Segmentation on the Kaggle Dataset - TGS Salt Identification Challenge. I have tried the code on both CPU and GPU using colab.

- Link to notebook file using CPU: bit.ly/2I2ZOMX_TGS_CPU
- Link to notebook file using GPU: bit.ly/2Vq0ROZ_TGS_GPU

In CPU notebook, I am getting the following error:
[Target 255 is out of bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EXYY.png)

I have set div = True in open_mask and have also set num_workers = 0

In GPU notebook I am getting the following error:
[CUDA error: device-side assert triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPtt0.png)

I have taken the custom metric of IOU.
Fastai version: 1.0.60

Kindly have a look and suggest me how to fix the issue.

Comment: The error is that you have 255 in your dataset, but your model does not have as many outputs. So, either clean your dataset to remove invalid classes, or modify your model if you that is a valid class.

Comment: Hi @akshayk07, thank you, but I am new to this. Would it be possible for you to have a look into the code and let me know how could I fix it?